# How to get the name of the variable containing the object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, variables

I can get the Class name of the Class with the code below:

```js
function MyClass() {
 return 42;   
}

var obj = new MyClass();

console.log(obj.constructor.name);
```

But how to get the name of the variable?

Comment: I may be mistaken but I don't think you can (unless you add a name property)

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem, why do you need the name of the variable?

Comment: @Jamiec to avoid creating a name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Consider:

```
function MyClass() {
    return 42;   
}

var obj = new MyClass();
var ob2 = obj;
var ob3 = obj;
```

There are now three variables all with the same value. Which one would you get if it was possible?

There's no reverse relationship between a variable and its value in JavaScript.

Comment: In your code, ob2 and ob3 are reference of the same object: obj. But if I intanciate 3 times, with "new" keyword, I got 3 differents objects right?

Comment: Because your point don't related to my question, but yes I admit I don't said enough details. I got 4 objects, instance of MyObject, and I want to get the name of these objects, but I think I will use an array or an object with a name attribute. Thanks.

Comment: @rickozoe — My point was that you can't do what your question is asking for. It is entirely about your question!

Answer (score 0):

This question defeats itself to a great extent. The use case for this is usually when you scan an object for certain key/value pairs. And even in the event that you want to foster through all global/window variables, you can still do:

```
for(var obj_name in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty && !window.hasOwnProperty(obj_name)) continue;
  console.log(obj_name);
  if(window[obj_name]) console.log(window[obj_name]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
function MyClass() {
   return 42;   
}

var obj = new MyClass();
var name = /function (.{1,})\(/;
var results = (name).exec(obj.constructor);
if(results)
{
    console.log(results[1])
}
```

Comment: I get 'MyClass'. What the thing, I ask for a question and people downvote me because it's impossible or they can't answer.